# How to flat an output of a select statement with UNION on the SQL level?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

Here is a select statement:

```
SELECT aField FROM myTable
  WHERE ID = pId and Name = 'C'
UNION ALL
SELECT aField  FROM myTable
  WHERE ID = pId and Name = 'CC'
UNION ALL
SELECT aField  FROM myTable
  WHERE ID = pId and Name = 'S'
UNION ALL
SELECT aField  FROM myTable
  WHERE ID = pId and Name = 'SC'
UNION ALL
SELECT aField  FROM myTable
  WHERE ID = pId and Name = 'R'
UNION ALL
SELECT aField  FROM myTable
  WHERE ID = pId and Name = 'RC';
```

Is a way to have the output data in a flat data set instead of a list?

Comment: You could look into a PIVOT query.

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'C' THEN RelativePath END) AS C,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'CC' THEN RelativePath END) AS CC,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'S' THEN RelativePath END) AS S,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'SC' THEN RelativePath END) AS SC,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'R' THEN RelativePath END) AS R,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'RC' THEN RelativePath END) AS RC
FROM myTable
WHERE ID = pId;
```

This assumes that you have at most one value for each name.

Comment: Thanks. This version works in the desired output format.

Comment: I have an additional question in regarding of this select statement: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34520241/to-retrieve-data-from-parent-child-tables-in-a-flat-data-set Can you help?