# To retrieve data from parent-child tables in a flat data set

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

Due to a bad existing DB schema design, I have to write a select statement in a special way as shown in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34301170/how-to-flat-an-output-of-a-select-statement-with-union-on-the-sql-level).

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'C' THEN RelativePath END) AS C,
   MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'CC' THEN RelativePath END) AS CC,
   MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'S' THEN RelativePath END) AS S,
   MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'SC' THEN RelativePath END) AS SC,
   MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'R' THEN RelativePath END) AS R,
   MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'RC' THEN RelativePath END) AS RC
FROM myTable
WHERE ID = pId;
```

Now, I need to join its output with an output of a select statement of its parent table. The structure of the parent-child tables is the following:

```
Parent
-------------------
id    -> the primary key
third_party_id
createdBy
createdDate
...

Child
-------------------
id -> the primary key of its Parent table
Name 
...
```

My desired output result of a select statement is something like the following for a given id:

```
third_party_id, createdBy, createdDate, C, CC, S, SC, R, RC
```

The child table may not have an entry for a given parent table key. I play with select statements with left join, but can't get the desired result. The DB is mySQL.

If a single select statement won't work, how to construct a stored procedure for the output?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
  Parent.third_party_id,
  Parent.createdBy,
  Parent.createdDate,
  Child.C,
  Child.CC,
  Child.S,
  Child.SC,
  Child.R,
  Child.RC
FROM
  Parent
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
  SELECT 
     ID,
     MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'C' THEN RelativePath END) AS C,
     MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'CC' THEN RelativePath END) AS CC,
     MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'S' THEN RelativePath END) AS S,
     MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'SC' THEN RelativePath END) AS SC,
     MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'R' THEN RelativePath END) AS R,
     MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'RC' THEN RelativePath END) AS RC
  FROM myTable
  GROUP BY ID
) Child ON
  Child.ID = Parent.ID
WHERE
  Parent.ID = pId;
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It can't get run however. There is a syntax error near the ON. I haven't see JOIN following by SELECT before.

Comment: Whats the exact error? And are you copying/pasting the above? The statement is syntactically correct.

Comment: I had a DB name in front of Child, something likes db_foo.Child, on the line "Child ON" as a table name reference used in the rest of query statement. That causes a syntax error. After removing the DB name, the query runs successfully. I also find that it doesn't take a table alias name on the line. Thanks very much for your help.